How can I change the cwd in a python terminal?
I've just started coding for a class and I'm trying to get used to VS Code, but I'm having some issues running a python program from the terminal.  I figured out how to change the powershell terminal's cwd to the correct folder that I'm storing my projects in; however when I create a new python terminal, the cwd is not correct.
I've already changed the "Terminal > integrated Cwd" setting to the correct file directory and I've tried changing the "Python > Testing: Cwd"; but opening a new python terminal still displays the wrong Cwd.
I read that a solution to a similar issue was to edit a .JSON file for VS code; but I'm fairly certain that this is a user issue as I just don't know what I'm doing in VS Code yet.  Any help would be much appreciated!
Current Cwds for Powershell and Python Terminals


What do you mean by "Python terminal"? Like, how do you create it? In the screenshot, the terminal is running PowerShell, not Python.

Oh, I just noticed there's a command, Python: Create Terminal (python.createTerminal) that just launches the shell... I have no idea what that's for.

If you just want to run Python code, that's covered in the tutorial.

yes that's how I was creating the Python terminal, sorry I'm using the wrong terms; but I don't know what the difference is between it and Powershell.  I can also still run the code using the 'Run' button in the upper right of the VS Code window; but in the tutorial they're running all the code via the terminal and I'm trying to figure out why I can't.  Just for more clarification, I'm attempting to run the code in the terminal with 'python Hello.py'  and the message I get is...

'C:\Users\juanc\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\Users\juanc\OneDrive\Documents\CS50\Python\hello.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory'  I'm just not sure how to change the directory it's pointing to.

I read about some similar issues that other people were having that were possibly issues with VS Code itself. I just don't want to attribute my issues to a bug without doing my do diligence, since I'm not familiar enough with VS Code to know what could be a bug or not.

So Hello.py is actually in Week_1, yeah? Then you can just use the PowerShell terminal, no? Once you have it open, then python Hello.py should work. You could of course use the "Python terminal" instead, but you'd have to cd Week_1 every time. Apart from the working directory, it doesn't seem to be any different from a regular terminal from what I can tell.

Ok that worked for me for now just like you described, thanks for the help I really appreciate it!

FYI: A shell is a program which allows you to interactively enter commands in the syntax of the respective shell: Powershell accepts Powershell commands, a Python shell accepts Python commands, zsh accepts zsh commands and so on. A shell can't leave in plain air, it needs a terminal where it is hosted. The terminal ensures that the output of the shell is rendered using the font of your choice, and transforms your typing on the keyboard into a stream of characters which is fed into the shell. There many terminals available and even more shells, and you need to find which combination you like.

You could use debug mode and set cwd in your launch.json.
See document about VSCode Debugging for more details.
If you just want to execute the scripts in the file's directory, you could check Execute In File Dir option in your Settings.


I'd question the assumption that you need to use the terminal at all.
It seems like you just need to run a Python script. If that's the case, you don't need to open a new terminal instance. Pressing the F5 key (debug) or CTRL+F5 (run without debugging) should run whatever script you currently have open without needing you to change your terminal cwd.

You can use the os python package to check your current working directory and project scope.
import os

# Change the current working directory (cwd) to "/tmp"
os.chdir("/tmp")

# Print the cwd
os.getcwd()


That would make sense if OP were running Python, but they're running PowerShell in the screenshot. I'm going to ask them to clarify the question.

Appologies, I covered the space between the screenshots and didn't think. The screenshots are of both terminals I have open, one is the powershell (on top) the other is a python terminal (bottom). The python terminal is where I need to change the cwd.

FWIW, there are existing highly-rated question about this: How to set the current working directory? and Equivalent of shell 'cd' command to change the working directory?
